# ws how to catch : WebSocket connection to 'ws:// failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: html, websocket

i have simple web sockets html5 , when the server is up every thing is working fine 
the problem is when i close the server ( for testing ) 
im getting :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:7777/api' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

which i unable to catch its never jumps to onerror  or onclose in case of this error

```
init: function () {
           this.m_wsiSendBinary = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7681/wsapi");

           this.m_wsiSendBinary.onopen = function(evt) {
               cc.log("Send Binary WS was opened.");
           };

           this.m_wsiSendBinary.onmessage = (function(evt) {


               this.handleServerResponse(yStr);


           this.m_wsiSendBinary.onerror = function(evt) {

           };

           this.m_wsiSendBinary.onclose = function(evt) {
               cc.log("m_wsiSendBinary websocket instance closed.");
               self.m_wsiSendBinary = null;
           };

}).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have full answer, however I dealt with similar issue and have a partial and not so elegant solution (but may help someone). Unfortunately without the elimination of the error message.

Two business requirements:

- BR1 - Handle state in initialization when the server is not available.
- BR2 - Handle state when the server stops.

Solution for BR1

```
var global_connection_openned=null;//Here you have the result
init: function () {
       global_connection_openned=false;
       this.m_wsiSendBinary = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7681/wsapi");
       this.m_wsiSendBinary.onopen = function(evt)
          {
             global_connection_openned=true;
          };
```

Solution for BR2 (assumes the BR1)

```
//somewhere in your project called by setInterval(..) which will detect the connection is lost (and tries to reestablish/reopen the connetion.
{
  if (this.m_wsiSendBinary==null || this.m_wsiSendBinary.readyState==3)
    this.init();

  if (!global_connection_openned)
    this.m_wsiSendBinary=null;
}
```

Anyway, I would be really curious if there is solid and proper solution of this use case.

Comment: Why you need the global var? is not enough with checking the WS state?